# How to make multiple lists collapse using Media Query

Tags: html, css, mobile-website, visual-web-developer

Hi there first time poster here!

I am making a website and needed help on how to make the section collapsible when the width of the screen shrinks. I wanted to know what could I add into the media query so the boxes instead of being displayed horizontally it is displayed vertically so one beneath the other card.

[Here is a picture of the section I am trying to make collapse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tXuS.png)

```
          <section id="prices" classes="bg-light">
        <div class="container">
          <h2 id="pricing-header">Our Rates<span class="text-primary"></span></h2>
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box">
                <h3 id="price-Heading">Basic</h3>
                <div class="icon-title">
                  <li> $50 </li>
                </div>
                <div class="icon-title">
                  <li> 1 page </li>
                </div>
                <div class="icon-title">
                  <li> 1 page </li>
                </div>
                <div class="icon-title">
                  <li> 1 page </li>
              </div>
              <div class="icon-title">
                <li> 1 page </li>
              </div>
              <div class="icon-title">
                <li> $50 </li>
              </div>
                <li class="icon-title"> $50 </li>
              </div>

          <div link class="box">
            <h3 id="price-Heading">Standard</h3>
            <div class="icon-title">
              <li> $100 </li>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-title">
              <li> $50 </li>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-title">
              <li> $50 </li>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-title">
              <li> $50 </li>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-title">
              <li> $50 </li>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-title">
              <li> $50 </li>
            </div>
              <li class="icon-title"> $50 </li>
            </div>

            <div link class="box">
              <h3 id="price-Heading">Premuim</h3>
              <div class="icon-title">
                <li>$250</li>
              </div>
              <div class="icon-title">
                <li> $50 </li>
              </div>
              <div class="icon-title">
                <li> $50 </li>
              </div>
                <li class="icon-title"> $50 </li>
              </div>

        </div> <!-- boxes ending -->
      </section>

      <!-- Pricing section Ends Here -->
```

Comment: Please show the css including existing media queries.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to stack your sections on mobile. This can very easily be achieved with flex-box, which is widely supported on browsers. Simply change how you justify the content and the flex direction within a mobile query.

```html
<style>
  .flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .section {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 20rem;
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 10rem;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .flex {
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="section">
    Section one.
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    Section two.
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    Section three.
  </div>
</div>
```

flex-direction will choose if its displayed on a row or stacked as columns. Justify-content will then choose how the items inside are positioned. Of course, in an ideal scenario, these styles would be in a separate file :-)